# Reading int value from txt file on SD card android

Tags: android, file, int, sd-card

So in this app I made, The user makes a project and when they save, the number of frames is saved to numberFrames.txt on the SD card. Then I retrieve the file in another class. Only thing is that nFrames = 50 when i show a toast of nFrames to the screen after I run this code. The only initializing of nFrames I do is to zero right above this code, which is located in the onCreate().

```
File sdcardLocal =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                 File dir = new File (sdcardLocal.getAbsolutePath() + "/Flipbook/"+customizeDialog.getTitle()+"/");
                 dir.mkdirs();
                 File fileNum = new File(dir, "numberFrames.txt");
                 FileWriter myFileWriter = null;
        try {
         myFileWriter = new FileWriter(fileNum);
        } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
                 BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(myFileWriter); 
                          try {
                           String text = bitmaps.size()+"";
                           out.write(text);
         out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I retrieve the file like this. I have no idea where this "50" value for nFrames came from as there are no loops around this and I know for sure that the particular project saved has only 3 frames. Why is this?

```
FileInputStream is = null;
             BufferedInputStream bis = null;
             try {
                 is = new FileInputStream(new File(mFolderDialog.getPath()+"/numberFrames.txt"));
                 bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                 nFrames = bis.read();
             }catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing out a string, and then reading the first byte as an integer. 50 is the ascii code for the '2' character.

You can use BufferedReader.readLine to read the entire first line of the file as a String, and then Integer.parseInt to convert that to an integer.

Also, I would take a closer look at your application's workflow. You don't give much information, but saving a file with a single integer value to the sdcard has a certain "smell" to it :). Have you looked at using a database, or maybe store the text file in your application's directory instead?

Comment: yea I was headed in the wrong direction. I found a way to get the number of items in a folder and that eliminated my need to save a txt file in the first place.